# vpn not listed in wireshark to analyze packets

Tags: vpn, wireshark, packet

I have vpn connection in my laptop. I am able to ping the vpn ip address successfully. I would like to analyze the network traffic and packets to and from vpn.So, I installed sharkwire But I dont see the listing of either VPN Name or the IP Address of VPN in wireshark. Any help?

Comment: What OS is your laptop running?  Windows?  If so, which version? Linux?  OS X?  Something else?

Comment: OS is Windows10. Also, I dont see ip address in the packet entries.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark uses WinPcap on Windows, and [some third-party VPN software doesn't work with WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm#Q-6) and [even some standard VPN software might not work with WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm#Q-5).  That might be the problem.

You could try installing [Npcap](https://github.com/nmap/npcap) and, if Wireshark uses it, that might fix the problem.  As its main page says, report problems on [Nmap's GitHub issues page](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues).